# Can't get navbar to expand in bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how can i get my navbar to expand , i have done everything right , i am using bootstrap4 and jquery  source files.

Am i missing something?

Here is my code:

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar py-3 navbar-light navbar-expand-sm">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-uppercase font-italic">first website</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarlink" aria-controls="navbarlink" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarlink">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#header" class="nav-link">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">projects</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: No it works fine: https://www.codeply.com/p/UexByZyQp8

Comment: Most likely you got some error in the path of the js files, please double check that both files get loaded by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The code works when I test `it` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adarshsingh87/j7hLgsva/) using the Bootstrap CDN. My guess is there might be an issue with linking the files. also make sure you have linked the Bootstrap CSS file in your code.